# Pip cannot install - error "Temporary failure in name resolution" on Debian WSL

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is my first stackoverflow question!

Recently python pip install has stopped working and is giving the following error:

pip3 install django

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f07a41b75c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/django/
```

The error repeats several times until it gives up.

I'm using Python3 in Linux Debian on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), on Windows 10.

After some searching and seeing some suggestions I found that my /etc/resolv.conf contains only:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

This doesn't look quite right... could this be the problem?

What is resolv.conf supposed to contain?

Thinking about what could be the root cause... before this happened the computer was accidentally switched off at the mains whilst apache2 and mysql services were running (in debian on WSL), could this have caused the problem?

Thanks in advance, Mark

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/resolv.conf` ([manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf)) usually only has a few, often automatically generated, lines that are pulled in from its network's configured DNS configuration.

In my WSL OpenSUSE, the entire resolv.conf file is:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, remove this line.
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

Which it pulls from the configuration in my home router.

I am not sure why your resolv.conf would be any different from that, unless it is something weird with the newer WSL2 that I have yet to try.

You can try manually configuring a nameserver or two with a public DNS like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8. Though that may not keep it from being overwritten until you figure out if there is an underlying problem.

---

On an installed Linux system instead of a WSL, that uses NetworkManager, it would be prefixed with `# Generated by NetworkManager` instead of the above WSL note.

Comment: As a side note: 1.1.1.1 is a Cloudflare product for encrypted DNS, which may cause issues for some services. 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are Google DNS products, which is not always the fastest but is reliable and easy to remember. There are lots of free DNS providers, but it can be well worth the effort to test their speed and reliability in your physical region of the world.